# Database/spreadsheet linking | Javascript for Gale Shapley Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-apps-script

I am on working on a java script code(Gale Shapley Algorithm). I want to read few entries from a database or spreadsheet and write the output of code in another database or spreadsheet.
My inputs are: 2 ranked preference matrices 
Output: Couples (there are two outputs from code, I need only 'couples'

Code:

```js
; Given a complete list of ranked preferences, where the most liked is to the left: 
bob := ["abi", "dee", "fay", "bea", "jan"]
gav := ["abi", "bea", "dee", "jan", "fay"]
ian := ["bea", "dee", "abi", "fay", "jan"]
jon := ["bea", "abi", "fay", "jan", "dee"]

abi := ["gav", "bob", "jon", "ian"]
bea := ["bob", "gav", "jon", "ian"]
dee := ["jon", "ian", "gav", "bob"]
fay := ["bob", "ian", "jon", "gav"]
jan := ["gav", "bob", "jon", "ian"]

 ; of ten males:
males := ["bob", "gav", "ian", "jon"]
 
; and ten females:
females := ["abi", "dee", "fay", "bea", "jan"]
 
; and an empty set of engagements:
engagements := Object()
freemales := males.Clone()
,s := "Engagements:`n"
 
; use the Gale Shapley algorithm to find a stable set of engagements:
For i, male in freemales ; i=index of male (not needed)
{
 j:=1 ; index of female
 While (engagements[female:=%male%[j]] != "" and index(%female%, male) > index(%female%, engagements[female]))
  j++ ; each male loops through all females in order of his preference until one accepts him
 If (engagements[female] != "") ; if she was previously engaged
  freemales.insert(engagements[female]) ; her old male goes to the bottom of the list
  ,s .= female . " dumped " . engagements[female] . "`n"
 engagements[female] := male ; the new engagement is registered
 ,s .= female . " accepted " . male . "`n"
}
 
; summarize results:
s .= "`nCouples:`n"
For female, male in engagements
 s .= female . " is engaged to " . male . "`n"
s .= Stable(engagements, females)
 

 
Msgbox % clipboard := s
Return
 
; Functions:
Index(obj, value) {
 For key, val in obj
  If (val = value)
   Return, key, ErrorLevel := 0
 Return, False, Errorlevel := 1
}
 
Stable(engagements, females) {
 For female, male in engagements
 {
  For j, female2 in females ; j=index of female (not needed)
  {
   If (index(%male%, female) > index(%male%, female2) 
    and index(%female2%, male2:=engagements[female2]) > index(%female2%, male))
    s .= male . " is engaged to " . female . " but would prefer " . female2
     . " and " . female2 . " is engaged to " . male2 . " but would prefer " . male . "`n"
  }
 }
 If s
  Return "`nThese couples are not stable.`n" . s
 Else
  Return "`nThese couples are stable.`n"
}
```

Comment: You could do everything in a single Spreadsheet file, and create separate sheets within the file for input/output. Could you include a sample output?

Comment: Output to above code is: abi is engaged to gav, bea is engaged to jon, dee is engaged to ian, fay is engaged to bob.